# UPDATE table element using data and id from another table

Tags: mysql, join, select, update

I need to update an element the row for id=N in table A with derived data from Table B.

Table A has `uid` as its primary key, and contains DATE element `foo`.

Table B has `a_uid` as an element, for each of which there are multiple rows for DATE element `b_foo`.

Conceptually, what I want to do is

```
UPDATE A SET foo=MAX(b_foo) WHERE uid = a_uid
```

Table A:

```
uid INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
foo DATE
```

Table B:

```
b_uid INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
a_uid INT(10) UNSIGNED,
b_foo DATE
```

I feel like this should be more obvious than I'm finding it to be; maybe it's because it's a COVID Monday? Regardless, many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called an `UPDATE JOIN`

First you must create a query that has the `MAX(b_foo)` for every `a_uid`:

```
SELECT a_uid,MAX(b_foo) max_b_foo FROM B GROUP BY a_uid;
```

Making this a subquery, you can perform the `UPDATE JOIN` as follows:

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN
(SELECT a_uid,MAX(b_foo) max_b_foo FROM B GROUP BY a_uid) C
ON A.id = C.a_uid SET A.foo = C.max_b_foo;
```

or you can get fancy and do

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN
(SELECT a_uid uid,MAX(b_foo) max_b_foo FROM B GROUP BY a_uid) C
USING (uid) SET A.foo = C.max_b_foo;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!